# What is the equivalent of Java's System.out.println() in Progress ABL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, println

I'm trying to implement Java's `System.out.println()` method in `Progress ABL`.

The closest functionality seems to be:

**test.p:**

```
MESSAGE "hello world" SKIP.
```

I ran the following tests to see if it works:

```
Windows
FAIL    C:\opt\prgs\dlc117\bin\prowin   -b -p test.p
OK      C:\opt\prgs\dlc117\bin\prowin   -b -p test.p | % ToString
OK      C:\opt\prgs\dlc117\bin\_progres -b -p test.p
OK      C:\opt\prgs\dlc117\bin\_progres -b -p test.p | % ToString

Unix
TODO
```

**So in the end, I'd implement it like this:**

```
METHOD STATIC PUBLIC VOID println(i_cText AS CHAR):

    MESSAGE i_cText SKIP.
    PAUSE 0.
    
    CATCH oError AS CLASS Progress.Lang.Error:
        /* Suppress error because MESSAGE doesn't support NO-ERROR. */
    END.
END.
```

I haven't found a way to know when the `MESSAGE` will fail. I tried checking `OPSYS`, `TERMINAL` and `SESSION:BATCH-MODE` but they are not reliable. I'd need to know if `default output` exists but how?

Comment: According to this: https://community.progress.com/s/article/Can-prowin32-prowin-or-progres-executables-on-Windows-write-to-standard-out-stdout it seems impossible to write to `stdout` in `Windows` when running in `batch` mode?

Comment: At least in ABL dojo `MESSAGE` works although it's running in `BATCH` mode? https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=649ad2c6d172aa40d044e1f3

Comment: There is nothing strange about ``message`` working in ``batch`` mode - if you are running a ``gui`` client you just need to ensure that you have opened the default stream yourself (``output to 'my.log'``) or you will get error 165. If you are running the character client (_progres) then output is sent to the console.

Comment: Question updated with new solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIAK you always have to redirect in order to execute in batch.
Your commandline without redirecting results in

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
** Attempt to write with no current output destination. (516)
---------------------------
```

Once you redirect, code below will write to stdout.

```
put unformatted "put Hello world".
message "message Hello world".
display "display Hello world".
quit.
```

you can use `| tee` on linux or `| % ToString` in powershell
result

```
prowin.exe -b -p .\helloworld_stdout.p | % ToString
put Hello world
message Hello world

display Hello world
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this redirection within the Progress code? Idea being, that if there's no output destination, the Progress could use default one without any configuration (using `STREAM`s and `OUTPUT TO`?

Comment: In ABL Dojo the `MESSAGE` works in batch mode. They either start that process with output redirect or it just works without redirect in `unix`?

Comment: as far as I know, there is no way to explicitly open stdout or stderr. Without the initial redirect you won't get past error 516