# What is the equivalent of Java's 'readLine()' in Progress ABL?

Tags: readline, openedge, progress-4gl

In `Java` you can read user input from the console with the following code:

```
String str = System.console().readLine("Enter value: ");
```

Is there a way to implement the same functionality in `Progress ABL`?

**After some research, I think the only way to implement this is to use WIN32 API calls.**

I think I got pretty close with the following code:

**test.p:**

```
BLOCK-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.
SESSION:ERROR-STACK-TRACE = TRUE.

PROCEDURE ReadConsoleInputA EXTERNAL "kernel32.dll":
    DEF INPUT  PARAM i_lhConsoleInput        AS LONG.
    DEF OUTPUT PARAM o_clpBuffer             AS CHAR.
    DEF INPUT  PARAM i_lnLength              AS LONG.
    DEF OUTPUT PARAM o_llpNumberOfEventsRead AS LONG.
    DEF RETURN PARAM r_iBytesReadSuccess     AS LONG.
END.

PROCEDURE GetStdHandle EXTERNAL "kernel32.dll":
    DEF INPUT  PARAM iHANDLE AS LONG.
    DEF RETURN PARAM oHANDLE AS LONG.
END.

DEF VAR hStdin      AS INT NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR inputBuffer AS CHAR NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(256)".
DEF VAR bytesRead   AS INT NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR nEvents     AS INT NO-UNDO.

FUNCTION ReadConsoleInput RETURNS LOGICAL ():
    INPUT THROUGH VALUE(inputBuffer).
    MESSAGE inputBuffer.
END.

/* Get handle to the console input */
RUN GetStdHandle(INPUT -10, OUTPUT hStdin).

MESSAGE "Enter input: ".

/* Read input from the console */
DO WHILE TRUE:
    nEvents = 0.
    
    RUN ReadConsoleInputA(
        INPUT hStdin,
        OUTPUT inputBuffer,
        INPUT 1,
        OUTPUT nEvents,
        OUTPUT bytesRead
    ).
    
    IF bytesRead > 0 THEN DO:
        
        ReadConsoleInput().
        
        /* Exit loop if input condition is met */
        IF inputBuffer = "quit" THEN
            LEAVE.
        
        IF nEvents > 1 THEN
            MESSAGE SUBST("'hStdin' '&1', 'inputBuffer' '&2', 'i_lLENGTH' '&3' 'bytesRead' '&4'", hStdin, inputBuffer, nEvents, bytesRead) SKIP.
    END.
    
    ASSIGN inputBuffer = "".
END.

MESSAGE "Program exited." SKIP.
```

It still fails to read the inputted character and the input is not written into the console normally, like with "readline()".

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Currently it seems that console input cannot be read when running in `BATCH-MODE` (non-interactive mode)

Comment: In batch mode you are explicitly saying that you do not have a console available.

Comment: Your fourth example prompts for input just like the first one does when I run it.

Comment: Ah, it seems that it couldn't run earlier because the file was compiled in Developer studio. Got the fourth one working!

Comment: I guess the final solution requires the usage of `BATCH-MODE` in combination of giving `Progress` the `stdin` access somehow. See related solution to `println`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76570422/2538037

Comment: Updated the question with the latest idea how to implement it.

Comment: What is your use case? This seems like an awful lot of work at fighting the language.

Comment: @TomBascom This is only for fun. I just want to see if I can implement a same kind of command-line read method like in other languages

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to readline.

When reading redirected input you can use IMPORT UNFORMATTED and get a line of input.

But IMPORT does not work with input directly from the console. You get this error:

```
define variable c as character no-undo.

import unformatted c.

** IMPORT requires a data source other than the screen. (1388)
```

You can get non-redirected console input to grab a whole line with something similar to this:

```
define variable c as character no-undo format "x(256)" view-as fill-in size 60 by 1.

update c.

message c.
```

The "x(256)" is means that the input line maxes out at 256 characters and the "60 by 1" gives you a 60 character wide fill-in field to type in.

But that doesn't seem to be what you are really after.

Comment: def var c as char label "Enter value:". update c.

Comment: For reasons that escape me just now that doesn't work any better. Only the data up to the first space will end up in the variable.  I did the FILL-IN thing on the assumption that in the interactive case there is a desire for a very long input line.